# auto generate model / variant in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, model, scope

I am a newbie in angularjs. Now i have an issue with angularjs.
My issue is: i have one textbox and a button 'addmore'. When user click addmore, new text field will be add in the template, and i want save the text user input in this text field !
User can 'addmore' with no limit. Now i cant get text in this text. Please see my code and show me what can i do ?

Many thanks

demo code: http://jsfiddle.net/g1Lenonj

```
    <div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="col-xs-12 enableDNS-cover">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="host_name">Search Domain</label>
                    <input type="text" id="host_name" name="host_name" class="form-control" ng-model="domainSearch"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div id='addServercontainer' class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="o_unit">Nameserver IP Address (IPv4 or IPv6)</label>
                            <input type="text" id="o_unit" name="o_unit" class="form-control" ng-model="enableDnsSetups['item_1']" placeholder=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <a id='addServerBtn' href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="enableDNSAddMore()"> + Add More </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        add data will be show here
        <pre>{{enableDnsSetups | json }}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
 function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.enableDnsSetups={};
    $scope.itemId = 1;
    $scope.enableDNSAddMore = function(){
        $scope.itemId ++;
        $scope.nameServerIpAddress = $scope.nameServerIpAddress + $scope.itemId;
        var serverField = " <div class='col-xs-12'><div class='form-group'><input type='text' id='o_name' name='o_name' ng-model='enableDnsSetups['item_'+itemId]' class='form-control' placeholder='' /></div></div>";
        $('#addServercontainer').append(serverField);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat` to loop over a list of the server containers. When a user clicks Add More, you can add another entry to this array. The `ng-repeat` will take care of adjusting the view. You should never manipulate the view manually from your controller.

Here's a [fork of your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27tkdjqq/1/) with my changes. There were inconsistencies between your JSFiddle and your question, so I just went with what you had in the fiddle.

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="col-xs-12 enableDNS-cover">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="host_name">Search Domain</label>
                    <input type="text" id="host_name" name="host_name" class="form-control" ng-model="domainSearch"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div id='addServercontainer' class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="item in dnsItems track by $index">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="o_unit">Nameserver IP Address (IPv4 or IPv6)</label>
                            <input type="text" id="o_unit" name="o_unit" class="form-control" ng-model="enableDnsSetups[item]" placeholder=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <a id='addServerBtn' href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="enableDNSAddMore()"> + Add More </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        add data will be show here
        <pre>{{enableDnsSetups | json }}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.enableDnsSetups = {};
    $scope.dnsItems = [];

    $scope.enableDNSAddMore = function() {
        var item = "item_" + ($scope.dnsItems.length + 1);
        $scope.dnsItems.push(item);
    };

    $scope.enableDNSAddMore(); // Call this function at initialization to start with 1 item
}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, i follow that way you suggest for me ! it work.